# Как читать SMS в приложении

Tags: ios, xcode

Я хочу сделать, что б сообщения поступающие на iphone с определенного номера можно было получить в приложении для дальнейшей работы с ним.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать? Или хотите что бы кто сделал это за Вас? Если первый вариант, то опишите что у Вас не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно. Apple не дает доступ сторонним приложениям к СМС по соображениям конфиденциальности.

Comment: Даже если SMS приходит через MFMessageComposeViewController в окошке? Можно полученный текст взять в обработку, мне нужно из полеченного текста выдернуть пару строк?

Comment: MFMessageComposeView‌​Controller - только для отправки SMS

Comment: Я имею ввиду в MFMessageComposeViewController окошке приходит ответ, можно оттуда взять строчку?

Comment: Нет, это не возможно, Вы можете только задавать текст, который хотите отправить!

Comment: Жаль! А как сделать так, что б окно MFMessageComposeView‌​Controller не вылезало? У меня есть кнопки с готовыми текстами отправки. Просто нажал на кнопку и сообщение ушло.

Comment: вот вам ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625499/send-sms-without-presenting-messagecomposeviewcontroller-in-ios

Comment: Я вас понял! Спасибо за ответ!